# git project manage with more branch(50)

Tags: git, project

Our company has a project, we have produced a system, and then sell it to other companies, we encountered a problem, is the project management problems, each client should have its own unique system, our system is also being developed how to manage the development of these projects.

We've tried using git branch function, a customer is a branch that we master their own development projects, for customers in the branches above customization.

Each master update, used above all in the branch rebase.

But after a few days, because of frequent changes to the master, rebase we encountered a lot of conflict. We spent a lot of conflict resolution at the time. Time cost is too high.

How should we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard problem to solve. Here are some thoughts:

1. The cleaner your coding style, the easier it will be to rebase clients on top of master. Books, like "Clean Code" by Bob Martin have a lot of information about how to write simple, clean, reusable code. One of the main points under all of it is that clean code is easy to change. This won't eliminate the need to fix conflicts, but it might make them easier to fix. A book like "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael Feathers, or "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing" by Fowler, Beck, et al., might help you figure out how to get master cleaned up to work better with the branches, but I can't promise that.
2. Good abstraction will help. If you have something that 10 customers need, don't put it in the 10 customer branches. Try to move it - cleanly, without breaking other things - up to master, and then simply use that new code in the branch. Other branches/customers should be able to safely ignore it.
3. Try to move customer specifics from code to data. If you have any customer-specific settings in the code, move them out to a text/JSON/YAML file. Each customer branch will have its own version of these files, and the master branch won't have any. Now you can work on the part of the code that uses these settings, and just let that grow as needs grow, and then all customers will have that code, but the settings will help decide what actually happens in each branch. No conflicts this way.
4. Move customer-specific functionality into plugins or helper scripts. This is like #3 above. You can't get conflicts with master if the files aren't even there. If a customer needs a custom formatter, put formatter.foo on their branch, and then just call to that formatter in the main code on that branch. If you get conflicts in the main program, at least they'll just be on one import line, or on the line that calls the function in that imported file.

Also, I wouldn't use rebase for this. I'd keep doing reintegration merges of master into the other branches. Rebase breaks the contract a bit. It says "this branch started here." That's not true, and it's less and less true the more often you rebase long-lived branches. Git does a good job of making all the changes in each commit, so code still works, but the code comments can start to get out of sync as they keep moving on top of possibly-refactored sections. The comment might say "Fixed issue in foo," but 30 commits ago 'foo' was renamed to 'bar', and someone reading that message now won't see foo in the code, because rebasing will have wiped all the 'foo' away. Merging leaves the bases where they are, and gives you a proper sense of where the histories were when things were originally made. Also, the longer the branches get, the longer it will take to rebase all the commits to the top again. Merges will only bring over what's new.

Comment: Thank you, I recommend you read a little of several books on programming is indeed a great help to me.
You said about not using rebase, after careful thought, you say makes sense, I will use the way you say